GraphQL Apollo Optimistic Response Adding Item and Updating Cache
I'm using GraphQL and Apollo with Shopify's Storefront API.
I'm trying to implement adding an item to the cart and I'm getting two of the same items in my cart. I will have an empty cart and when I add to the cart, I get two of the same item. When I remove them from my cart, they both get removed since they have the same CartLineID.
I was debugging and saw that it was adding the same item to the cache with the same ID and I thought Apollo takes care of that under the hood so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here.
Am I not supposed to update my cache here? I thought for mutations I have to handle the cache myself. I know that optimistic responses will automatically add it to cache so I'm confused on what I'm supposed to do for the cache update. Even the example on Apollo's documentation says I concat the existing list with my new item. This makes sense but because optimistic response will automatically add the item, it's add itself twice.
So am I supposed to not update the cache or use optimistic response for adding an item?
Is it because I'm missing a field and it's detecting it's not the same response and that's why it's not merging properly?
Here is my GraphQL Query / Mutation:
export const FETCH_CART = gql`
  query fetchCart($cartId: ID!) {
    cart(id: $cartId) {
      id
      lines(first: 10) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            quantity
            merchandise {
              ... on ProductVariant {
                id
                image {
                  url
                }
                title
                price {
                  amount
                  currencyCode
                }
                product {
                  id
                  productType
                  title
                }
                sku
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      totalQuantity
      cost {
        checkoutChargeAmount {
          amount
          currencyCode
        }
        subtotalAmount {
          amount
          currencyCode
        }
        subtotalAmountEstimated
        totalAmount {
          amount
          currencyCode
        }
        totalAmountEstimated
        totalDutyAmount {
          amount
          currencyCode
        }
        totalDutyAmountEstimated
        totalTaxAmount {
          amount
          currencyCode
        }
        totalTaxAmountEstimated
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const ADD_TO_CART = gql`
  mutation AddCartLine($cartId: ID!, $lines: [CartLineInput!]!) {
    cartLinesAdd(cartId: $cartId, lines: $lines) {
      cart {
        id
        lines(first: 10) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              quantity
              merchandise {
                ... on ProductVariant {
                  id
                  image {
                    url
                  }
                  title
                  price {
                    amount
                    currencyCode
                  }
                  product {
                    id
                    productType
                    title
                  }
                  sku
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

await addCartLine({
          variables: {
            cartId,
            lines: [
              {
                merchandiseId: newItem.id,
                quantity: 1,
              },
            ],
          },
          optimisticResponse: getOptimisticAddToCartResponse(cartId, {
            id: newItem.id,
            quantity: 1,
            title: newItem.title,
            price: newItem.msrp,
            currencyCode: 'usd',
            url: newItem.feature,
            productId: newItem.productId,
            productType: newItem.type,
            sku: newItem.sku,
            variantTitle: newItem.variantTitle,
          }),
          update(cache, { data: { cartLinesAdd } }) {
            const addedLine = cartLinesAdd.cart.lines.edges[0].node; // Assuming only one line is added
            updateAddToCartCache(cache, cartId, {
              id: addedLine.id,
              quantity: addedLine.quantity,
              title: addedLine.merchandise.title,
              price: addedLine.merchandise.price.amount,
              currencyCode: addedLine.merchandise.price.currencyCode,
              url: addedLine.merchandise.image?.url, // Optional chaining for safety
              productId: addedLine.merchandise.product.id,
              productType: addedLine.merchandise.product.productType,
              sku: addedLine.merchandise.sku,
              variantId: addedLine.merchandise.id
            });
          },
        });

My optimistic response:
export const getOptimisticAddToCartResponse = (
  cartId: string,
  newLine: {
    id: string;
    quantity: number;
    title: string;
    price: number;
    currencyCode: string;
    url: string;
    productId: string;
    productType: string;
    sku: string;
    variantTitle: string;
  }
) => ({
  cartLinesAdd: {
    cart: {
      id: cartId,
      lines: {
        __typename: 'BaseCartLineConnection',
        edges: [
          {
            __typename: 'BaseCartLineEdge',
            node: {
              id: `temp-line-${Date.now()}`,
              quantity: 1,
              merchandise: {
                __typename: 'ProductVariant',
                id: newLine.id,
                image: {
                  url: newLine.url,
                },
                title: newLine.variantTitle,
                price: {
                  amount: newLine.price,
                  currencyCode: newLine.currencyCode,
                },
                product: {
                  id: newLine.productId,
                  productType: newLine.productType,
                  title: newLine.title,
                },
                sku: newLine.sku,
              },
              __typename: 'CartLine',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      __typename: 'Cart',
    },
    __typename: 'CartLinesAddPayload',
  },
});

My add to cart cache update:
export const updateAddToCartCache = (
  cache: ApolloCache<any>,
  cartId: string,
  newLine: {
    id: string;
    quantity: number;
    title: string;
    price: number;
    currencyCode: string;
    url: string;
    productId: string;
    productType: string;
    sku: string;
    variantId: string;
  }
) => {
  debugger;
  // Read the existing cart from the cache
  const existingCart = cache.readQuery({
    query: FETCH_CART,
    variables: { cartId },
  });

  if (!existingCart) return;
  // Add the new cart line to the existing cart lines

  const updatedLines = [
    ...existingCart.cart.lines.edges,
    {
      node: {
        id: newLine.id,
        quantity: newLine.quantity,
        merchandise: {
          __typename: 'ProductVariant',
          id: newLine.variantId,
          image: {
            url: newLine.url,
          },
          title: newLine.title,
          price: {
            amount: newLine.price,
            currencyCode: newLine.currencyCode,
          },
          product: {
            id: newLine.productId,
            productType: newLine.productType,
            title: newLine.title,
          },
          sku: newLine.sku,
        },
        __typename: 'CartLine',
      },
      __typename: 'BaseCartLineEdge',
    },
  ];

  // Write the updated cart back into the cache
  cache.writeQuery({
    query: FETCH_CART,
    variables: { cartId },
    data: {
      cart: {
        ...existingCart.cart,
        lines: {
          __typename: 'BaseCartLineConnection',
          edges: updatedLines,
        },
        __typename: 'Cart',
      },
    },
  });
};

